# Adjacent Sibling Selectors with specificity of an enclosing class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this DOM:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have this css rule:

```
.b + .c { margin-left: 220px; }
```

BUT only within class `a`

I was hoping that something like this would have worked , but no luck.

```
.a .b + .a .c {}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this selector instead:

```
.a .b + .c {
    margin-left: 220px;
}
```

... or `.a > .b + .c`, if you want the rule to be applied only to the children of `.a` container, rather than to all its descendants.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/edspB/).

Now for explanation part. As defined in [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax), every selector with `+` symbol is treated as selector chain:

> A selector consisting of a single simple selector matches any element
>   satisfying its requirements. Prepending a simple selector and
>   combinator to a chain imposes additional matching constraints, so the
>   subjects of a selector are always **a subset of the elements matching
>   the last simple selector.**

Now that's analyze the expression you've started with:

```
.a .b + .a .c
```

According to spec, this is actually treated as...

```
((.a .b) + .a) .c
```

In other words, selector is applied...

- to all the `.c` elements, which...
- ... have `.a` elements as their ancestors, which...
- ...... have `.b` elements as their preceding siblings, which...
- .......... have `.a` elements as their ancestors.

This selector will match `.c` element in this HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">This is matched</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case, however, you won't have to check for `.c` ancestry - it's enough to check for `.b` (its preceding sibling) only. If `.b` has `.a` up its DOM tree, its *sibling* sure has it too. )

Comment: Updated the answer with an explanation, hope this'll clear the things. )