# How can I target a block after another block with css?

Tags: html, css

My html looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="myItemClass">item foo</li>
  <li class="myItemClass specialItemClass">item foo</li>
  <li class="myItemClass">item foo</li>
  <li class="myItemClass">item foo</li>
  <li class="myItemClass specialItemClass">item foo</li>
  <li class="myItemClass specialItemClass">item foo</li> <!-- problem here -->
  <li class="myItemClass">item foo</li>
  <li class="myItemClass">item foo</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to define a css-style for an item that has the 'specialItemClass' and is located after an item that has the 'specialItemClass', too. How can I do that?

Further explanation: The 'specialItemClass' includes having a 2px coloured border. But if two special items are right beneath each other, the borders are doubled. So I don't want to add the special border at the top [or bottom] if there's another special item above [or below].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use adjecent css3 selector to work around your issue.
its better to have mere specific selector.
Please see the fiddle

```
li.specialItemClass + li.specialItemClass{
  border-top:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3a02u/

Comment: That jsfiddle is interesting :) If I add the id "mysuperclass" to the ul-element and then add ul#mysuperclass  to the css, it doesn't work anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3a02u/1/ Any idea why?

Comment: have a look at this answer for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717677/adjacent-sibling-selectors-with-specificity-of-an-enclosing-class

Comment: so earlier jsfiddle gives solution to youe issue in this particular scenario

Comment: Yes, the first answer gave a solution to my particular scenario. But when I tried it in my real scenario it didn't work, because of the issue that is described in the other stackoverflow-question you linked. Thanks for your detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the adjacent sibling selector [**+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```
.specialItemClass + .specialItemClass{
    /*styles here*/
}
```